# Azure Data Factory V2 SFTP Error

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to perform a copy activity using Azure Data Factory V2 and configured source and sink properties, everything looks fine. When i executed the process, it fails with the below error. I tried with a different SFTP server but still getting same issue.

*Please make sure Sftp server is not throttling ADF Service or Integration Runtime (Self-hosted)., Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.SftpConnector,''Type=Renci.SshNet.Common.SftpPathNotFoundException,Message=No such file,Source=Renci.SshNet,'*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not due to the path or file not found but its due to the MaxSessions setting at SFTP server. I set this property in SFTP server and it works !!

Comment: I encountered a similar error where an _SshAuthenticationException_ was raised, but there actually was not an authentication issue with the SFTP server. Setting the **Max concurrent connections** to 1 in the Copy Data - Source corrected the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

The message is clear, "Path not found exception" and "No such file" means that when it builds the path with folderPath+fileName and tries to navigate to it, the path doesnt work. Try fixing that, at least its not an authentication issue.

Hope this helped!